# How to blur image with gradient diffusion smoothing filter using edge preserving

Tags: matlab, gradient, smoothing

How can I blur an image using an edge preserving gradient diffusion smoothing filter in matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use  Daniel Lopes's [Anisotropic Diffusion (Perona & Malik)](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14995-anisotropic-diffusion-perona-malik) tool   available in the Matlab's FEX.  Or Peter Kovesi's [anisodiff.m](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/Research/MatlabFns/#anisodiff) code.